# Simple Circuit to stream video

Tags: components, lcd, video

I want to stream online video to an LCD screen from a phone or tablet. In the circuit will also be an accelerometer, battery, and perhaps a cache (if this would improve streaming). What kinds of parts should I buy? I am not sure if I need a processor, not sure if I should use Bluetooth, wifi-direct, something else. And what kinds of chips do you use for that. Sorry I'm kind of lost. I want it to be as small as possible as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything involving video is never simple. It sounds like your best bet would be a cheap tablet as the target screen..

Comment: I'm more than willing to learn. Is there a tutorial somewhere you could recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more of an undergraduate degree sized course than a tutorial, if you're trying to do it *from scratch* rather than re-purposing existing hardware. If I were going to do it I'd start with an Android tablet, a "digital photo frame", or a Raspberry Pi in a box. Disable the touchscreen and write your own software, using the existing video decode.

You haven't said anything about the format of the video, so I'm assuming it's digital rather than NTSC or PAL.

You'd need a processor with hardware video decoding and a network stack. These exist, but first you have to find one that's available in quantity 1. You probably also want it hand-solderable, which is a serious problem (most will be BGA). Same problem for associated RAM, network chipset, etc. Then you need a suitably high quality multilayer PCB, which is likely to start at $50-$100 for quantity 1.

Comment: Im getting LCDs from a manufacturer. Could you post a link to the parts you mention? I would be in your debt.

Comment: e.g. https://www.intersil.com/en/products/audiovideo.html or http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM131/SC999/SS1629/PF216978

Comment: What course would this be?I want to take it this semester?